# What is a "picolo" (slang)?

Tags: sens, argot

I encountered the following sentence:

> *la personne est abonnée au vigne de france habite en bretagne sûrement un picolo.*

This is how I get it:
"the person is subscribed to the French version of Vine, he lives in the UK, he is surely a Picolo"

I couldn't find what "picolo" means here, and also I am not sure if I understood "vigne" correctly (I understood it as the app Vine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Picolo" is like alcoholic.

"Bretagne" is region of France too.

"Vignes" : the vineyards where the grapes are walking

Comment: Thank you very much! I have two questions: now I see that there is a place called Les Vignes de France near Paris region. Maybe "vigne de france" refers to this region? and the second question: what it means "est  abonnée au vigne de france"? to be subscribed to a vineyard?

Comment: No don't think it refer to this region. Think it's like subscribing to a wine magazine. Difficult to explain without the context

Answer (score 3):

"Les vignes de France" is a wine seller.
As said before, a "picolo" is an alcoholic, and "Bretagne" is Britany in English.

So, your sentence could be translated in:

> The person is subscribed to "Les Vignes de France", he lives in Britany, he is surely an alcoholic.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence has no punctuation and is written entirely in lower case. The only way I can make sense of it is by interpreting it as follows:

> La personne est abonnée au [magazine] Vignes de France, habite en
> Bretagne; sûrement un picolo.

Then the meaning is: “The/that person is a subscriber of Vignes de France, [and] lives in Brittany; probably a drunkard.”

Comments:

- While ”vignes de France” can be many things, for a person to have been subscribed to something with that name I can only think of *Vignes de France*, a 1950s monthly publication of the Institut technique du vin.
- In a French context, *Bretagne* is always Brittany, the French region. Britain is *Grande-Bretagne*.
- The word *sûrement*, especially when used casually, often means ‘probably’ rather than ‘certainly’ or ‘surely’.
- *Picolo* (sometimes *piccolo*) is a slang version of *picoleur*, ‘drunkard‘, itself derived from the (now dated) identical term *piccolo*, ‘cheap wine’ (a loan from the Italian).

Answer (score 0):

In this context, "La personne est abonnée aux vignes de France" can be simplified by "The person enjoy French wine".